# how many arithmetic operation can be made at right side of a variable

Tags: java, math

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        int a = i + j*2;
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

when run the above code I am getting output as

```
3
46
579
681012
79111315
```

I am not able to understand why it is printing first row as 3, i+j*2 =4 as per the logic.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. It will allow you to step through your program and see what each line does.

Comment: I don't think you do get that output. There is nothing there which prints new lines.

Comment: Why do you think `1+1*2` is 4? I believe it's 3.

Comment: *"when run the above code I am getting output as"* Not with that code. As @Andy says, you're never outputting newlines, and if you change `print` to `println`, you get something very different: http://ideone.com/kApjly Oh, I see, you've left out the `println` you're doing after the inner loop: http://ideone.com/O0RLUv That seems like a **very** strange way to write the results of numeric operations, since it produces seriously-confusing output.

Comment: You might benefit from knowing the basics of operation priorities in math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not able to understand why it is printing first row as 3, i+j*2 =4 as per the logic.

Precedence. Multiplication takes precedence over addition, so on the first call, `i+j*2` is `1+1*2` which is `1+(1*2)` which is `1+2` which is `3`.

The precedence of basic operations can be remembered with PEMDAS or BODMAS (the "MD" and "AS" have the same precedence, so I've shown them on a single line here):

```
P          Parentheses / Brackets            B
E          Exponenentiation / Orders1        O
MD         Multiplication & Division         DM
AS         Addition and Subtraction          AS
```

<sup>1</sup> Powers (2^5), square roots, etc.

The Java site has [a page on operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), which has this table:

```
postfix                expr++ expr--
unary                  ++expr --expr +expr -expr ~ !
multiplicative         * / %
additive               + -
shift                  << >> >>>
relational             < > <= >= instanceof
equality               == !=
bitwise AND            &
bitwise exclusive OR   ^
bitwise inclusive OR   |
logical AND            &&
logical OR             ||
ternary1               ? :
assignment             = += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=
```

---

<sup>1</sup> They mean the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), which is *a* ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands) and as it happens, the only one Java has.

Comment: Is it only multiplication or all arithmetical operation

Comment: You could be right. When we are in primary school we don't know what maths will be useful for, but in programming it is +1

Comment: @ABAJAVa Java follows rules of precedence just like basic maths.https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html

Comment: That's great, But here both are positive integers.. which are doing addition operation.

Comment: @ABAJAVa: The sign of the operands is irrelevant to precedence, I'm not sure what you're asking there.

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to understand little bit. I will work on it more and get back if any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication (`*`) has arithmetic precedence over addition (`+`). In the first iteration, `i` and `j` are both `1`. The first thing to be calculated is `j*2`, i.e., `1*2=2`. Then we add `i` and the previously calculated product and get `1+2=3`.